# how to work out the missing function problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: the missing function problem photoshot]

I can try many possibles, and take a long time to workout the result, I would like to know if there is a better way to solve this problem?

it's coming from 11 years test book, I thought it must not quite hard than I am looking into.

Comment: How are you supposed to fill those squares? The 5 to 4,8 to 5, 11 to 6 is already a function.

Comment: figure out the function to fill in the 2 boxes, to suit 5 to 4, 8 to 5, 11 to 6.

Comment: Function is of form ax+b so that 5a+b = 4. Work out a and b using simultaneous equations and check the third 11 to 6 works too.

Comment: Any thoughts on Paul's comment, or on the answer I posted yesterday, 3127293?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $5,8,11$ increase by $3$, whereas $4,5,6$ increase by $1$, so the answer will involve dividing by $3$. Now start at the right end, and work your way back to the left. Multiplying by $3$, that $4,5,6$ came from $12,15,18$. Now it should be easy to see what to do to $5,8,11$ to get $12,15,18$, and then you're done.

Comment: thank you very much, this is straightforward solution, why I didn't work on this way? :)